# Python: Beautiful Soup not printing when using requests.get

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to run the below code in Pycharm and I'm getting `"Process finished with exit code 0"` which I'm guessing means that the program is running, but nothing is being printed. I've made sure that I have `beautifulsoup`, `requests`, and `lxml` installed correctly. I'm not sure what else could be wrong mainly cause I copied it from corey schafer's video and it ran fine for him.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
source = requests.get('https://coreyms.com/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it produces an output.

Comment: Did you install the `lxml` parser with `pip install lxml` in your prompt command?

Comment: It's working for me, too, assuming you remove the backticks at the start and end.

Answer (score 0):

Install `html5lib`.

By using `pip install html5lib`

After downloading Try this code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code instead!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://coreyms.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```